# How to write udf in c++ for oracle db

Tags: c++, oracle11g

I want to write a UDF in c++ for Oracle database(11g).I already achieved this in c language but don't know how to do it in c++.I am new to all these things.Tell me How can I achieve this.Here is my c-code---

```
               #include <stdio.h>
                #include <stdlib.h>
               int add_number(int num1,int num2)
               {
                int sum=0;
                sum=num1+num2;
                 return sum;
                  }
```

Comment: Can you post the C code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you are writing the UDF in CPP, add the function declaration inside

```
extern "C"{

/*Functions with same parameters as in the definition*/
}
```

So,in your case the code would look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern "C"{
int add_number(int num1,int num2);
}
int add_number(int num1,int num2)
{
    int sum=0;
    sum=num1+num2;
    return sum;
}
```

After this rest all the steps like compilation, creation of function would remain same, hope that would work.